# Cannot write to /dev/fb0 in systemd-nspawn container

Tags: permissions, framebuffer, systemd-nspawn

I've created a systemd-nspawn container in which `/dev/fb1` from the host is bound as `/dev/fb0`. I've set `PrivateUsers=off` in the .nspawn config file, and the file ownership and permissions of `/dev/fb0` in the container appear to be the same as `/dev/fb1` on the host. Running `cat /dev/urandom >/dev/fb1` on the host works as expected ('no space left on device' error), but if I boot the container, and log in to it as root (with `machinectl`) `cat /dev/urandom >/dev/fb0` fails with 'Operation not permitted'. I also tried to write to it using `dd -if /dev/urandom -of /dev/fb0`, and that gave the error 'dd: failed to open '/dev/fb0': Operation not permitted'. I've tested other commands that would require root access, such as `chmod` and `chown`, and my root user in the container is able to run those.

If I bind `/dev/fb1` as itself (i.e. just `Bind=/dev/fb1`), then the write operation *is* permitted.

Does anyone know why I can't open the file for writes from within the container?

This is the .nspawn config:

```
[Exec]
Capability=CAP_SYS_ADMIN
PrivateUsers=off

[Files]
Bind=/dev/fb1:/dev/fb0
Bind=/srv
```

This is the systemd-nspawn service override file for the container:

```
[Service]
DeviceAllow=/dev/fb0 rw
DeviceAllow=char-input rw
DeviceAllow=char-drm rw
```

(I'm sure some of this config is unnecessary -- I've just been chucking in everything I can think of to solve my problem.)

Comment: Have you tried changing "DeviceAllow=/dev/fb0 rw" to "DeviceAllow=/dev/fb1 rw"? From the perspective of the host system (where the service override is applied), the container is trying to access /dev/fb1 (even though the container sees it as /dev/fb0).

Comment: @ATLief, thanks for the suggestion. I don't think I tried that, though the fact that the binding was writable when it was bound as /dev/fb1 (i.e. not renamed in the container) makes me think that you might be on to something. I can't test it now, but I'll try when I next get a chance.